# Android - Conexão com PostgreSQL

Tags: android, postgresql, eclipse

Estou tentando conectar o `Android` diretamente com `PostgreSQL`.
Incluir no pacote do projeto: **postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc4.jar** e estou usando `PostgreSQL 9.1`.

Porém não consigo realizar a conexão com sucesso.

Modifiquei o código e ele me retorna:

> "Erro: Driver!"

Estou usando `JDBC`: **postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc4.jar**.

---

Modifiquei o código e está dando erro:

> Conexão: Erro Database!

Segue o código:

```
// Conectar
public String conectarDB() {

    // Variáveis
    String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database";
    String user = "postgres";
    String pass = "123456";

    try{

        //Carrega o driver
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
        return "Conexão: Ok!";

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Conexão: Erro Driver!";

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Conexão: Erro Database!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? tem log?

Comment: Como faço para vê o log e lhe enviar?

Comment: Adicione isto ao **catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return false;}** e verifique a aba inferior **Android Monitror**

Comment: Não estou utilizando o Android Studio é muito pesado para máquina que estou usando. Mesmo sem PostgreSQL não é exibo erro algum nem mesmo com  } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();  return false;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Há necessidade de carregar o Driver antes de se conectar, segundo [esta documentação.](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/load.html)

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
 public boolean conectarDB() {

        try{
            //Carrega o driver
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database";
            String user = "postgres";
            String pass = "123456";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

            if (conn != null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Já incluir. Infelizmente o erro continua. Obrigado!